# Paperclip AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey error on copy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I'm trying to copy avatars from a different model into my `User` model but am getting an `AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey` error when I try to do that.

Here's the code that throws the error:

```
old_avatar = OldAvatar.find(1)
user = User.find(old_avatar.user_id)
user.avatar = old_avatar.avatar
user.save
```

The `user.avatar = old_avatar.avatar` line is what throws it.

Here is my `OldAvatar` model...

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :styles => { 
                      :t => '20x20#',
                      :s => '40x40#',
                      :m => '50x50#',
                      :b => '80x80#',
                      :f => '100x100#' 
                    }, 
                    :storage => :s3, 
                    :s3_credentials => { 
                      :access_key_id => APP_CONFIG['s3_access_key_id'], 
                      :secret_access_key => APP_CONFIG['s3_secret_access_key']
                    },
                    :path => ":attachment/:id/:basename:normalized_style.:extension", 
                    :url => "/:attachment/:id/:basename:normalized_style.:extension",
                    :bucket => "old_bucket"
```

And here is my `User` model...

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                      :styles => { 
                        :t => '20x20#',
                        :s => '40x40#',
                        :m => '50x50#',
                        :b => '80x80#',
                        :f => '100x100#'
                      },
                      :storage => :s3, 
                      :s3_credentials => { 
                        :access_key_id => APP_CONFIG['s3_access_key_id'], 
                        :secret_access_key => APP_CONFIG['s3_secret_access_key']
                      },
                      :bucket => "new_bucket",
                      :path => ":attachment/:id_partition/:basename_:style.:extension",
                      :url => "/:attachment/:id_partition/:basename_:style.:extension"
```

Do note, I'm copying between two different buckets (as noted in the different model model code), so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Seems like it's just a 404. Are you getting this for a case where you know for a fact that the image exists?

Comment: @FareeshVijayarangam Yes, I do know the image exists.

Comment: @FareeshVijayarangam If I log `old_avatar.avatar`, it correctly shows the path to the image I'm trying to copy.

Comment: I guess the problem lies in the left hand side of the assignment in that case, which could only mean that there is a problem assigning *anything* to `user.avatar`. If you try and assign a `user.avatar` manually does that work? If not, it's probably something to do with the last two lines of the `User` model in the code you've linked, i.e. the path/URL parameters are not working. Does the `"new_bucket"` exist?

Comment: I can assign `user.avatar` manually and vice versa...I just can't seem to copy between the two. And yes, both buckets do exist.

Comment: I suppose your best option is to write some code that converts the 1 line assignment to the manual process which you are referring to. Perhaps the gem is messing up somewhere when it comes to copying between models.

Comment: I think @FareeshVijayarangam might be somewhat right, the issue seems related to a gem update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had some inconsistent paths for some early images and so they didn't match the path I set for Paperclip (thus the wrong image URL was generated).

So, problem solved.

Comment: It seems there are consistency issues between the routes generated by Paperclip 3.0.x and 2.x. If you're updating gems for a live site it might be a good idea to fix your Paperclip gem version. This might somewhat justify your "solution", but I think you didn't write inconsistent paths, but the new version of the gem generates paths differently from the previous versions.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to fix a No Such Key error while running the paperclip rake tasks provided by spree to resize images that were previously uploaded this also was very helpeful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844281/can-not-run-rake-papercliprefreshthumbnails-class-spreeimage-in-rails-spre/16844282#16844282

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because of a misnamed size identifier using `:regular` instead of `:normal`. Since there was no `:regular`, it gave me this error.