# Can not run 'rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=Spree::Image' in rails spree app console getting No Such Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip, spree

I am trying to `RAILS_ENV=production run rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=Spree::Image`

on my remote server in my current rails app directory, so I can refresh the spree images that I have uploaded in the past.

I am using S3, my bucket is setup correctly as I can see each of my product's images in individual ID folders in my AWS S3 bucket.

But each time I run the above command I get a 'No Such Key' Error when the rake is aborted.

This command runs locally and works fine. (obviously without the RAILS_ENV=production locally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I wrote this question to answer it myself. I hope the question makes sense.

For clarity, I had this issue because it was old images (old non existing paths that were associated with an old S3 Key) that I had uploaded with another S3 Key in previous testing on the same rails app. I did this earlier while trying to get S3 to work with my Rails Spree Application.

What I did to solve this was go into my Rails console on my remote server with this command:

$`RAILS_ENV=production rails c`

I then ordered the list of all Spree:Images them with this:

$`y Spree::Image.all(:order => 'attachment_updated_at')`

The 'y' is a nice little yaml way of displaying the information of the Spree:Image that's a little more human.

Next I looked at the ID of each Image and noticed that there was a good amount of them with IDs that did not match folders in my AWS S3 bucket.

In my Case the lowest ID number that was in fact a folder in my S3 bucket was '1078' so I ran this:

$`Spree::Image.where('id < ?', 1078).destroy_all`

This deleted any Spree::Image that had an ID of 1077 or less.

Finally, I closed rails console and ran this on my remote server inside my current rails app directory. (In my case is was /home/deployer/apps/potentialapp/current/)

$`RAILS_ENV=production rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=Spree::Image`

This reformatted my uploaded images on Spree and everything is now working great.

Hope this saves someone a great big headache. (Oh and empty your cache when you go to test and see if the images have in fact reloaded, almost cried at 4 am last night.)

Comment: @samuelkobe..I am also facing the same problem but I am able to run the command `rake paperclip:refre...` but still the images are appearing darker. My command log clearly states -> `deleting app/products/32/1.jpg` and `saving app/products/32/1.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem using the console and skipping errors (old/broken S3 assets):

```
Spree::Image.all.each { |i| i.attachment.reprocess! rescue nil }
```